# Перегрузка оператора [][] в C++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

У меня есть класс "Матрица". И в нём нужно перегрузить оператор `[]` так, дабы при обращении `[][]` к элементам имело смысл, аналогично встроенному. Пробовал так:

```
Matrix& operator[][](int a,int b);
```

Не получилось, поиски в *Google* ни к чему не привели. Может кто-то знает как реализовать?

Comment: Покажите объявление объекта, к которому будет применяться этот оператор.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Определите оператор `[]`, который будет возвращать строку - как указатель, вектор или еще что-то, для чего определен оператор `[]`, который будет возвращать ссылку на конкретный элемент...

Простейший пример:

```
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(int R, int C):R(R),C(C)
    {
        d = new int*[R];
        for(int i = 0; i < R; ++i)
            d[i] = new int[C];
    }
    ~Matrix()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < R; ++i)
            delete[] d[i];
        delete[] d;
    }

    int* operator[](int idx) { return d[idx]; }
    const int* operator[](int idx) const { return d[idx]; }
private:
    int ** d;
    int R, C;
};

int main()
{
    Matrix M(3,3);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            M[i][j] = 10*i + j;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            cout << setw(2) << M[i][j] << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

Естественно, никакие ошибки у меня не обрабатываются.